# How can I check if printer is in some state longer than 30 minutes?

Tags: powershell, logging

I have a script, checking state of all printers from all print-servers through WMI. Result looks like this:

```
Name                            location                       Status                                                   
----                            --------                       ------                                                 
Xerox wc275.1                                                  Offline                                   
dnj-4000.1                                                     Offline                                 
6040.1                                                         Offline                        
m225.02                                                        Offline                                  
5225.01                                                        Offline
```

How can I check if printer is offline for 30 minutes? I can put an output in a text file for logging or smth? All I need is the "how it can be done". Later I will configure email notifications etc. But I don't know nothing about logging and parsing in powershell.

Comment: Check status every x minutes, and if you get the same status ("offline") on a total of 30 minutes, maybe you can consider it was offline over that period of time. 30min may be a bit long for a refresh interval (printer may go online and offline suring that timespan).

Comment: It just a simple status. No matter what is it, offline, online, error or smth. I just want to know how can I check it with powershell. If I will check status every x minutes.. don't think it's a good idea. Will it be better  to remember the pool of offline printers and check it with timespan?

Comment: How can you know if it's been offline for 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

If you're outputting these results to a text file every half hour, you could use Compare-Object to report back on differences/similarities between 2 files:

```
$file1 = get-childitem -path "C:\Powershell\Test\Text" | sort LastWriteTime | select -ExpandProperty FullName -last 2 | Out-File C:\Powershell\path1.txt
$file2 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\path1.txt" | Select-Object -First 1
$file3 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Powershell\path1.txt" | Select-Object -Last 1
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $file2) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $file3) -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | sort InputObject
```

In this, List1.txt contains:

```
Xerox wc275.1                                                  Offline                                   
dnj-4000.1                                                     Offline                                 
6040.1                                                         Offline                        
m225.02                                                        Offline                                  
5225.01                                                        Offline
```

List2.txt contains:

```
Xerox wc275.1                                                  Offline                                   
dnj-4000.1                                                     Online
6040.1                                                         Offline                        
m225.02                                                        Offline                                  
5225.01                                                        Online
```

So the result gives the lines that are the same as 30 minutes previously:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\Powershell\Test\CompareMostRecentFiles.ps1

InputObject                                                                                                      SideIndicator                                                                                                  
-----------                                                                                                      -------------                                                                                                  
6040.1                                                         Offline                                           ==                                                                                                             
m225.02                                                        Offline                                           ==                                                                                                             
Xerox wc275.1                                                  Offline                                           ==
```

Notes:

This checks the 2 most recent files in a particular folder, so if you're running a printer check every 30 minutes and exporting to a text file, make sure the text files are being output to their own specific folder that do not contain anything else, otherwise you won't get correct results. You will also need to ensure your printer check script creates unique text files and doesn't keep overwriting the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Done it using infinite loop.

```
    $printers = @{}

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | 
ForEach-Object {
    $printers[$_.Name] = $_ |
    Select-Object Name,DetectedErrorState,@{Name='PreviousStatus';Expression={$_.DetectedErrorState}},@{Name='StatusTime';Expression={0}}
}

Do {
    $check = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer
    ForEach($printer in $check) {
        If($printers[$printer.Name].DetectedErrorState -ne $printer.DetectedErrorState) {
            $printers[$printer.Name].PreviousStatus = $printers[$printer.Name].DetectedErrorState
            $printers[$printer.Name].DetectedErrorState = $printer.DetectedErrorState
            $printers[$printer.Name].StatusTime = 0
        } Else {
            $printers[$printer.Name].StatusTime += 1
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep 60
} While ($True)
```

Big thanks to mr.Cduff for this idea.